# Graph Cut Problem

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have a problem as such:

> $2n$ players, each of whom has an odd number of friends, are
> distributed into two teams. A player is happy if more of his friends
> are on the other side than on his own side, and a distribution is
> stable if everyone is happy. The cut number of a distribution is the
> number of friends belonging to the opposite teams.
>
> Give an example of two different stable distributions of the same set of players that have different cut numbers.

I don't know how to attack this. I've tried drawing graphs and trying to construct two such matchings for low values of $n$, but no success so far. I need a hint.

Comment: Is friendship symmetric?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by symmetric, but it's commutative, i.e. if A is friends with B, then B is friends with A. There is one link connecting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got an example. Take $12$ vertices; call them them $a_i,b_i,c_i,\;d_i,1\le i\le3$. Draw $24$ edges as follows: $9$ edges $a_ib_j$, $9$ edges $c_id_j$, $3$ edges $a_id_i$, $3$ edges $b_ic_i$. This is a $4$-regular bipartite graph. Put the $a$'s and $c$'s on one team, the $b$'s and $d$'s on the other; everyone is happy, and the cut number is $24$. Next, put the $a$'s and $d$'s on one team, the $b$'s and $c$'s on the other; again everyone is happy, but the cut number is only $18$. Right?

**P.S.** That example was bigger than it needed to be. Here is an example with $8$ vertices ("players") and $12$ edges ("friendships"): **the cube**, with vertices $000$, $001$, $010$, $011$, $100$, $101$, $110$, $111$.

Partition the vertices into the Even Team $\{000,011,101,111\}$ and the Odd Team $\{001,010,100,111\}$; everyone is happy; each player sees all three friends on the other team; all $12$ edges are "cut".

Partition the vertices into the Blue Team $\{000,001,110,111\}$ and the Red Team $\{010,011,100,101,\}$; each player sees one friend on his own team and two friends on the other team; everyone is still happy, but only $8$ edges are "cut."